# finding how many options ls have

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Just for practise i want to find out how many options does ls command have. I have written following piece of code

```
man ls | grep -o -i '\-[a-z0-9]$'
```

Why does this piece of code only printed `-C and -V`?

Answer (score 0):

Because not all options are the last thing on a line in the man page, in fact very few of them are.

e.g. most option lines will be like:`-a, --all`

I'm not 100% sure if it will get them all, but try this:

```
$ man ls | grep -E -o -i -- ' {7}-[a-z0-9], --[A-Z]+| {7}-[A-Z0-9] | {7}--[A-Z0-9]+' | 
    sed -e 's/^  *//'
-a, --all
-A, --almost
--author
-b, --escape
--block
-B, --ignore
-c 
-C 
--color
-d, --directory
-D, --dired
-f 
-F, --classify
--file
--format
--full
-g 
--group
--sort
-G, --no
-h, --human
--si
-H, --dereference
--dereference
--hide
--indicator
-i, --inode
-I, --ignore
-k, --kibibytes
-l 
-L, --dereference
-m 
-n, --numeric
-N, --literal
-o 
-p, --indicator
-q, --hide
--show
-Q, --quote
--quoting
-r, --reverse
-R, --recursive
-s, --size
-S 
--sort
--time
--time
-t 
-T, --tabsize
-u 
-U 
-v 
-w, --width
-x 
-X 
-Z, --context
-1 
--help
--version
```

That will get both short and --long options.

The above applies to GNU `ls`.  It may or may not apply to other versions of `ls`

Answer (score 0):

Parse `ls --help`, it seems easier. Using `grep` with PCRE (`-P`), not including long options e.g. `--all`:

```
ls --help | grep -Po '^\s+\K-[^,\s](?=,|\s)'
```

Parsing `man ls` would give the same result:

```
man ls | grep -Po '^\s+\K-[^,\s](?=,|\s)'
```

**Example:**

Parsing `ls --help`:

```
% ls --help | grep -Po '^\s+\K-[^,\s](?=,|\s)' 
-a
-A
-b
-B
-c
-C
-d
-D
-f
-F
-g
-G
-h
-H
-i
-I
-k
-l
-L
-m
-n
-N
-o
-p
-q
-Q
-r
-R
-s
-S
-t
-T
-u
-U
-v
-w
-x
-X
-Z
-1
```

Parsing `man ls`:

```
% man ls | grep -Po '^\s+\K-[^,\s](?=,|\s)'
-a
-A
-b
-B
-c
-C
-d
-D
-f
-F
-g
-G
-h
-H
-i
-I
-k
-l
-L
-m
-n
-N
-o
-p
-q
-Q
-r
-R
-s
-S
-t
-T
-u
-U
-v
-w
-x
-X
-Z
-1
```